# Set different session expiry time for different users in Django

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

How can I set different session expiry time for different logged-in users? The scenario can be, admin can permit certain users some time(like 4 hrs in a day) to use the application. After that time limit is over the user is logged out of the system and cannot log in again until the admin permits again. Is there any way I can implement this in Django?

Answer (score 2):

You can set expiry time of `session` by

```
request.session.set_expiry(300)
```

Where 300 is in seconds so this session will expire after 300 seconds. For your case, you can set different amount of seconds depending on users.

Referrence: [Django Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry)

Comment: But then if the user logs in again, it should not permit log in until admin allots the permission.

Comment: you can manually query in `Django session` by `self.request.session.session_key` and check the expire_date